# MongoDB getting killed on read load

Tags: mongodb

Standalone mongodb on heavy read load is getting killed..

I see no instance of mongo being OOM killed in kern.log.. is there any way I can debug the root cause?

I looked at mongo logs -

db version 2.6.1 -

```
mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x4fb) [0x117720b]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182) [0x7f82e5391182]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f82e469630d]
2014-08-27T08:37:29.584+0000 [conn28] 808.autoComplete Assertion failure a <= 512*1024*1024 src/mongo/util/alignedbuilder.cpp 104
2014-08-27T08:37:29.601+0000 [conn28] 808.autoComplete 0x11c0e91 0x1163109 0x1146f4e 0x1144f9d 0xa6370f 0xa639c4 0xa563f7 0xa56a9a 0xa53e8f 0xa53f46 0xc3e557 0xc4a0f6 0xb90169 0xb9a388 0x76b6af 0x117720b 0x7f82e5391182 0x7f82e469630d  mongod(_ZN5mongo16MyMessageHandler7processERNS_7MessageEPNS_21AbstractMessagingPortEPNS_9LastErrorE+0x9f) [0x76b6af]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x4fb) [0x117720b]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8182) [0x7f82e5391182]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f82e469630d]
2014-08-27T08:37:29.652+0000 [conn28] dbexception in groupCommit causing immediate shutdown: 0 assertion src/mongo/util/alignedbuilder.cpp:104
2014-08-27T08:37:29.652+0000 [conn28] SEVERE: gc1
2014-08-27T08:37:29.661+0000 [conn28] SEVERE: Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
Backtrace:0x11c0e91 0x11c026e 0x7f82e45d1ff0 0x7f82e45d1f79 0x7f82e45d5388 0xb8c1bb 0xa5683d 0xa56a9a 0xa53e8f 0xa53f46 0xc3e557 0xc4a0f6 0xb90169 0xb9a388 0x76b6af 0x117720b 0x7f82e5391182 0x7f82e469630d
```

Comment: Please put more context, like mongodb version used.....

Comment: Are you indexing very large arrays? See [this JIRA issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12080) or [this one](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14751).

Comment: @wdberkeley.. u r right.. I did look at the JIRA ticket for this.. Finally, removed a document which had 600000 elements in an array..

Comment: @wdberkeley Can you please put it as an answer? It will be more visible..